# Incorrect substitution and formatting formula on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've made a formula that can change the date format off MM/DD/YYYY and MM-DD-YYYY to "mmm". However it only works for cells that have "/". How do I fix this formula?

```
=TEXT(SUBSTITUTE((LEFT((TEXT((SUBSTITUTE((F33),"-","/")),"mm/dd/yyyy")),10))," ",""),"mmm")
```

[image: Screenshot]

Cheers

Comment: It seems that the date 9-13-2019 is TEXT format, I suggest you try to transform the TEXT to Date&Time format first.

Comment: In first look,, row 5 downwards looks a like TEXT value but even the Formula should works,, I've successfully applied formula and getting Month Name !!

Comment: The report that I use is generated with all of the values being a 'General' format, the only way that I was able to work around it being in that format was to use SUBSTITUTE, then TEXT to replace the '-' with '/' and then format it correctly. 

Even if I simply change it into a custom format as mm-dd-yyyy it returned incorrect values, is there another way to work around that?

Comment: Your report is being imported incorrectly into Excel.  As a result, some "dates" are real dates, and others are text strings.  Start by properly importing your data. Then formatting will be much simpler.

Comment: That's the issue, it's not in my control how the data is generated, the formatting issue has been raised to the company that we are getting the data from and they have been MIA on a solution for a while, that is why I'm trying to work with what I have @RonRosenfeld

Comment: What kind of file is being supplied by the source company?

Comment: CSV, PDF, TIFF, EXCEL and WORD. However I cannot use the excel file because their data is presented in tables with a lot of hidden and closed rows/columns so I cannot copy the data from it.

Comment: Use the csv file, and import it; don't open it. Then you can tell excel what the date format is in the csv file.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld how exactly do you import it, and change the format of the date in excel without opening it? Is there a link or video on how I can do this? Cheers

Comment: Another weird thing is, this formula worked fine in another spreadsheet that was entirely filled with general date formats and the formula was able to convert it and return the month as intended, I'm not sure why it is an issue here? I'm guessing it might be because the column that I'm trying to convert in the OP is a mixture of general and real date formats.

Comment: I don't believe your formula is returning the correct month as intended by the CSV file creator.  See my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the date format in the CSV file, and your Windows Regional short date (WRSD) format are different.

Excel will parse dates according to your WRSD settings, which are likely DMY.  So when the second part of the date is >12, it become text. And dates that do not become text will have the D and M reversed from what they should be. This is likely because the CSV settings are MDY.

To handle this, you can either change your WRSD to MDY **before** opening the CSV, or  you can **import** the CSV file.  This will open the text import wizard, and give you a chance to tell Excel that the dates in the CSV file are MDY, overriding your WSRD.

Importing the file is different in different versions of Excel.  But, in general, you navigate to the Data tab and look for something that shows "from text".  That should pop up a file selection dialog.

If you have O365, you may need to select Transform Data from the subsequent dialog in order to get to where you can define the date column properly; in earlier versions you should see something like the text-to-columns wizard which will afford the same function.

Then, to get the month, you either format the column as `mmm` or use a simple text function:  `=text(cell_ref, "mmm"`

It is likely that with the non-text dates, your formula is not returning the month intended by the CSV file creator.  It seems to be correct due to the method you use with the text string.  A "real date" will display the month with the simple formula shown above.  You can see if they agree in your right-justified dates.